# Specify "Simplify" output to see steps

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the equation:

$$w=\frac{b(r+s)+\theta q(\theta) \lambda p}{r+s+ \theta q(\theta) \lambda } + \lambda \left(p - \frac{b(r+s)+\theta q(\theta) \lambda p}{r+s+\theta q(\theta) \lambda}\right)$$

which I know can be simplified to:
$$w=b+(p-b)\frac{\lambda(r+s+\theta q(\theta))}{r+s+\theta q(\theta) \lambda}$$

However, I can't figure out how to obtain the second form of the equation from the first one. Is there a way to tell Mathematica both the input *and* the desired output of the "simplify" command and then see the steps?

Comment: This looks relevant: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/783066